# Why is d_reclen variable

Tags: linux, filesystems

I can get the size of struct dirent precisely using sizeof operator。In my PC it printed 280.Its definition in dirent.h is as follows.

```
struct dirent
  {
#ifndef __USE_FILE_OFFSET64
    __ino_t d_ino;
    __off_t d_off;
#else
    __ino64_t d_ino;
    __off64_t d_off;
#endif
    unsigned short int d_reclen;
    unsigned char d_type;
    char d_name[256];       /* We must not include limits.h! */
  };
```

It's correct.But I also noted that d_reclen is a member that shows the length of the record,it prints numbers like 24, 32, 40.etc.
So in memeory, which one is the real size of the struct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact of `sizeof()` showing 280, even if that reflects the real room for the struct in memory, is a don't care. Albeit `d_name` is `[256]` in this *particular* definition, POSIX defines it as `d_name[]`, a character array of unspecified size. Depending on directory name size (shorter / longer), one indeed should be able to observe different values in `d_reclen`, such as 24 or 32 in the above example.

Please see "**The d_name field**" section under "**NOTES**" in the [man](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) page.

The short of it, doing `sizeof()` on `d_name` is incorrect. Applications should either use `d_reclen` or perform `strlen()` on `d_name` to know the name length.

Comment: Thanks.I have considered what you said. I just can't understand why they designed such a member in this struct , maybe it can help to get next dirent quickly?

Comment: For the implementation in question, yes, it can probably facilitate easier entry traversal. But from the application perspective, it's a don't care. Consequential invocations of `readdir()` return `dirent` entries, one by one, and that should be pretty sufficient.

Comment: I tested it with a  short program which traverses a designated directory.I found that the address of the adjacent dirent just differs by d_reclen bytes.The kernel may has do some space optimization to avoid allocating 280 bytes for every dirent struct.

Comment: That matches what the answer is saying. One should not rely on 280. This observation of yours kind of confirms that (each entry is of `d_reclen` bytes in the actual memory size). That should be fairly correct.